# When I try to run a run.sh file, it says another .sh file is not found. How do I solve this?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Hey so I have downloaded this (clicking on this hyperlink downloads) http://cs-people.bu.edu/sameki/LabelMe.zip into ubuntu via command line, and I go to the folder to find a run.sh to run. But when I run it says another file loadHITS.sh not found.

What do I do when I have such error? I'm working first time with ubuntu etc. I'm just following instructions from a PDF

EDIT: The PDF I'm working with is this - http://cs-people.bu.edu/sameki/blog1.pdf

Comment: Did you extract the archive? Please [edit] and add the output of `ls -l`.

Comment: Have you downloaded something else that you wish to use this in conjunction with? These scripts are meant to be run from inside a directory that is inside a directory containing the "missing" scripts (in a folder called bin)...

Comment: You may well need to run `chmod a+x ./loadHITS.sh && ./loadHITS.sh` or cd into the directory containing loadHITS.sh and / or use the full path to loadHITS.sh . Cant tell from what you posted

Comment: Please post the exact error text or better yet whole output from `run.sh` script.  Additionally, the pdf instructions you mentioned would be great to add, too.

Comment: Hey @JoshuaBesneatte so I found something called loadHITs.cmd not loadHITs.sh, but it was another level up than what you said. Should I just move my current downloaded document(this zip) by one folder up? many thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte to make things clear, in a Directory AWS-MTURK, there is a folder bin and samples. In bin I have the loadHITs.cmd, and in the samples, I have another directory LabelMe, which has the run.sh

Comment: try going to the folder with loadHITs.cmd and run this "ln -s loadHITs.cmd loadHITS.sh" and see if that work

Comment: Hey @JoshuaBesneatte after trying what you said it initially said permission denied. I have did chmod a+x  ./loadHITs.sh. Now when I ran it there were a bunch of errors like below [link] (https://imgur.com/DstVJJN) . Could you please take a look? thank you!!

Comment: try "sudo apt install librem-dev"

Comment: also, are you certian that the turk stuff you downloaded isn't for windows?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte no luck :/ Yea it should work for Ubuntu because for all of the tutorial (PDF) he assumed it was ubuntu, and when I initially tried in windows I wasn't able to run the run.sh file

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the script, there seems to be much more to it. It appears to be a folder that is to be placed somewhere where these scripts exist. Have you installed or downloaded something that these scripts are meant to work with?

When the script runs, it tries to go up two directories and look for a folder called bin, where the scripts are to be located.

First you need to see if you have this file somewhere on your system. You can use locate from the command line:

```
sudo apt install locate
sudo updatedb
locate loadHITs.sh
```

If you can locate this file on your system, or post what you find and I can tell you where to place the folder so that it will work. Otherwise you will need to find the necessary scripts to work in conjunction with this set of scripts.

Comment: Hey I have tried it, there is no loadHITs.sh anywhere. So I'm working with amazon Turk, and basically what this zip file should do is integrate my server to the Turk. The PDF I'm following instructions from is this - http://cs-people.bu.edu/sameki/blog1.pdf. If you look at the end of PDF it says to put the above Hyperlink into the aws-mturk directory. As per what you said, there was no loadHITs.sh anywhere even in above directory. Any chance the loadHITs.sh is 'created'? Thanks for the reply!!

Comment: from a quick look at that pdf you need to install turk command line tools.... and either the server needs to look to your secure server to pull the lable me files or you need to install the turk command line tools https://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-Mechanical-Turk/694